# Multiple log4j.xml in a jar files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am developing a client api where I have a specific requirement to log the client api specific log messages to a separate file and it is pretty straight forward: I created an appender and associated the appender with logger which is specific to my package.

Now the question is:

What happens if the client application has its own log4j.xml? How will my appender and logger work in that environment ?

Comment: They will need to put your appender on the classpath, and then reference it in their log4j.xml.

Comment: @crush I just give them the jar file which includes the log4j.xml. If the jar file is in the classpath the xml will also be in the class path right ?Correct me if I am wrong. and the requrement is also that the client should not have any burden/or need to to be aware of how we are logging internally.

Comment: See my EDIT at the end of answer

Comment: If you don't "own" the logging, it might make sense to use SLF4J http://www.slf4j.org  This would let the person you deliver the jar to use whatever logging framework they want, and configure it however they want.

Comment: My question is around the class which I wrote and I want the log to be printed in a specific file...

Answer (score 1):

The log4j initialization process only handles one configuration file - thus this file should contain all logging configuration that should be active. You probably have to define a specific configuration for the client application that contains your and the client applications logging configuration.

The client application has to be configured to use this file for the initialization. This is done by setting the `log4j.configuration` system property as described in the [log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) (suppose that you are using log4j 1).